# Facebook Flash send HTTP request to Own Server. Does Facebook proxy the call?

Tags: flash, facebook, proxy, httprequest

For javascript aJax call, I know the data will be proxy by facebook.  Session data will follow the same rule as FBML.

and now, I have a Flash component.  I know Facebook will pass fb user data (and session data) to the flash as parameters.  However, when the flash talks to the server, does facebook proxy it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flash does its HTTP using the embeding browser ... i don't know how facebook proxies calls, but I guess, they just overwrite the browser API to intercept calls ...

now depending on browser, this may or may not affect flash player ... i guess, the most easy way is to look at the request when it hits your server ...